# Stop turning bare URLs in RFC 2606 domains into links

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, auto-linking

## The Problem

[Sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15885794/383793) on Stack Overflow (and —how meta­— on [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175725/171231)) you talk about URLs and use an [RFC 2606](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.example#Reserved_DNS_names) domain (such as 'http://example.com'), but you will never mean this to be a hyperlink. These URLs are meant as examples, not as links to be followed.

The extra style gives it unwanted emphasis. Currently I use `` to mark it as code and prevent it becoming a hyperlink, but that gives it even more emphasis.

Is there a way to suppress the [bare URL](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#bare-urls) behaviour?

## The Proposal

If there isn't one, I *don't* think we should introduce one, as I disagree with *[Must URLs always be hyperlinked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164999/must-urls-always-be-hyperlinked)*.

I think we should exempt bare URLs to RFC 2606 domains from becoming hyperlinks. One could always force it with <> if one really feels the need.

---

The ["duplicate"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175665/171231) asks for [support](/questions/tagged/support) and doesn't propose a feature. The [accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175669/171231) actually is what I said I am using at the time I asked this, but am not satisfied with. (That time was a mere 5 hours after the duplicate. Which, combined with the lack of use of the "bare URL" terminology from the FAQ in that duplicate, might explain why I didn't find it, in spite of my extensive work.)

Answer (score 28):

You could escape a character:

```
http:\//example.com
```

http://example.com

Comment: Very clever.. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @Chris No, I don't think so.

Comment: I think the answer would be appropriate for [Hidden features of Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-overflow) as well as [Formatting Sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Is it a bug, that the preview shows the `\`? I'm looking for a report, but http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/preview-should-match-the-posted-view seems to have been deleted.

Answer (score -3):

You could escape, but that uses extra characters... Using lookalike glyphs works too:

- http:╱╱example.com
- http:
  //example.com
- http:
  //example.com
- нttp://example.com
- hттp://example.com
- hեեp://example.com
- httpः//example.com

I like this one the best: hߚp://example.com it's actually a character less. ;-)

As [Arjan comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175725/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-bare-urls-becoming-hyperlinks#comment527131_175732), this is **not** a recommended solution.

It's not totally useless knowledge though, as the use of lookalike glyphs has been used to trick people into trusting a [man-in-the-middled lookalike ssl](http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/) protected domain. So always check the bold domain part in the location bar when you use https.

Comment: Apart from [possible rendering problems](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4ua0l.png), this also might yield surprises for copy & paste, and I doubt a screen reader will like it. Escaping is just as easy, I feel, *and* has no side effects I can think of. (And as for counting characters: the special glyphs surely will use additional *bytes* over the wire.)

Comment: @Arjan you're absolutely right. Hence the ;-). It's a tongue in cheek answer.